Pass reference of struct to multiple struct members
I need to create a struct for a shared library that is supposed to be passed out called Application. But I need substructs that access the db field and perform operations with it. There will be about 20 of those sub structs that themselves have about 20 methods each.
use infrastructure::modules::database::Database;

pub struct Application {
    db: Database,
    a_commands: ACommands,
    b_commands: BCommands,
}

impl Application {
    pub fn new(db: Database) -> Self {
        Self {
            db,
            a_commands: ACommands::new(&db),
            b_commands: BCommands::new(&db),
        }
    }
}

struct ACommands {
    db: &Database
}

impl ACommands {
    pub fn new(db: &Database) -> Self {
        Self {
            db
        }
    }
}

struct BCommands {
    db: &Database
}

impl BCommands {
    pub fn new(db: &Database) -> Self {
        Self {
            db
        }
    }
}


I get lifetime issues and borrow checkers errors.
Am I going about this the right way? How else would I create and structure a public struct in a library with hundreds of functions?
Cheers.

You can use one lifetime for everything, or owned containers if you prefer.

I'd recommend either using an Arc (db: Arc<Database>) or storing Database directly in Application (db: Database) and passing a reference to it when calling methods

Here's some example code for my earlier comment:
Arc:
use std::sync::Arc;
use infrastructure::modules::database::Database;

pub struct Application {
    db: Arc<Database>,
    a_commands: ACommands,
    b_commands: BCommands,
}

impl Application {
    pub fn new(db: Database) -> Self {
        let db = Arc::new(db);
        Self {
            db: db.clone(),
            a_commands: ACommands::new(db.clone()),
            b_commands: BCommands::new(db.clone()),
        }
    }
}

struct ACommands {
    db: Arc<Database>,
}

impl ACommands {
    pub fn new(db: Arc<Database>) -> Self {
        Self {
            db
        }
    }
}

struct BCommands {
    db: Arc<Database>,
}

impl BCommands {
    pub fn new(db: Arc<Database>) -> Self {
        Self {
            db
        }
    }
}

Storing Directly:
use infrastructure::modules::database::Database;

pub struct Application {
    db: Database,
    a_commands: ACommands,
    b_commands: BCommands,
}

impl Application {
    pub fn new(db: Database) -> Self {
        Self {
            db,
            a_commands: ACommands::new(),
            b_commands: BCommands::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn execute_a_command(&self) {
        self.a_commands.do_something(&self.db);
    }

    pub fn execute_b_command(&self) {
        self.b_commands.do_something(&self.db);
    }
}

struct ACommands;

impl ACommands {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self
    }

    pub fn do_something(&self, db: &Database) {
        println!("A did something")
    }
}

struct BCommands;

impl BCommands {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self
    }

    pub fn do_something(&self, db: &Database) {
        println!("B did something")
    }
}

Arc allows multiple structs to share ownership of the Database instance, and even seamlessly works across threads, and since you're not modifying Database itself you could also use an Arc to provide read access.
On the other hand, storing Database directly in Application and then passing a reference to it when calling methods on the sub-structs keeps the borrowing more explicit while avoiding  having the sub-structs hold onto the references.

I used the solution with Arc and it works great! Thank you

I extended it to Arc<Mutex> because I need a mutable reference

Assuming this is primarily/exclusively for command grouping, you don't need to have the Commands on hand, you could instantiate them with methods like so:
pub struct Application {
    db: Database,
}

impl Application {
    pub fn new(db: Database) -> Self {
        Self { db }
    }
    // lifetime is inferred from &self
    pub fn a_commands(&self) -> ACommands<'_> {
        ACommands::new(&self.db)
    }
    pub fn b_commands(&self) -> BCommands<'_> {
        BCommands::new(&self.db)
    }
}

pub struct ACommands<'a> {
    db: &'a Database,
}

impl<'a> ACommands<'a> {
    pub fn new(db: &'a Database) -> Self {
        Self { db }
    }
    pub fn command_a1(&self) -> i32 {
        todo!()
    }
    pub fn command_a2(&self) -> &str {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct BCommands<'a> {
    db: &'a Database,
}

impl<'a> BCommands<'a> {
    pub fn new(db: &'a Database) -> Self {
        Self { db }
    }
    pub fn command_b1(&self) -> f32 {
        todo!()
    }
    pub fn command_b2(&self) -> Option<u8> {
        todo!()
    }
}

and use them like this:
let application = Application::new(Database);

// create a short lived wrapper for multiple calls
let a = application.a_commands();
let val_a1 = a.command_a1();
let val_a2 = a.command_a2();

// or call directly from the returned value
let val_b1 = application.b_commands().command_b1();
let val_b2 = application.b_commands().command_b2();

They only exist for the duration of the function calls, so they can't be stored anywhere else, but it does allow you to group the commands you're creating in a logical way, and potentially store other state that you need with them (i.e., adding a field to the ACommands struct that you initialize in the call).
Because these are purely just wrappers, they function as 0-cost abstractions, and won't impose a performance penalty. You can also further compose more nested commands that are only available on BCommands, for example:
impl<'a> BCommands<'a> {
    pub fn c_commands(&self) -> CCommands<'_> {
        CCommands { db: &self.db }
    }
}

pub struct CCommands<'a> {
    db: &'a Database,
}

impl<'a> CCommands<'a> {
    pub fn new(db: &'a Database) -> Self {
        Self { db }
    }
    pub fn command_c1(&self) -> f32 {
        todo!()
    }
    pub fn command_c2(&self) -> Option<u8> {
        todo!()
    }
}

let val_c1 = application.b_commands().c_commands().command_c1();

